# What happens when I try to remove handler that was never added?

Tags: .net

I have an event handler.
I add an event 5 secs after start to it like this:

```
AddHandler MyHandler, AddressOf DoStuff
```

Now when disposing the whole form, I need to

```
Private Sub Unsubscribe()
     RemoveHandler MyHandler, AddressOf DoStuff
End Sub
```

What if I close the form earlier than 5 secs after start? Is it a problem when I try to `RemoveHandler` that was never added? Is it the same in c# with `+=` and `-=`?

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: Nothing happened, but my colleague tells me it is wrong.

Comment: Did he elaborate why it is wrong? It is not rude to ask for evidence for such claims.

Comment: Did they tell you what to do instead and why? Don't let people tell you something is wrong without an explanation.

Comment: @Fildor yes but I could not understand and hoped to find better explanation here.

Comment: Well, "better" is relative. _Any_ (correct) explanation is "better" than _no_ explanation. Unfortunately I didn't find that case covered in the docs at first glance. And not knowing what exactly your colleague was referring to, I have a hard time giving you an explanation. Fact is, I knew you can remove handlers without adding them all day long. But I have to admit, I don't exactly know why. (I can think of reasons, but I still have no proof.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the day, this winds up working with [`MulticastDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate?view=netframework-4.7.2)s, and the action of `RemoveHandler` (VB) or `-=` (C#) is to call [`RemoveImpl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.multicastdelegate.removeimpl?view=netframework-4.7.2), which returns:

> If `value` is found in the invocation list for this instance, then a new Delegate without `value` in its invocation list; otherwise, this instance with its original invocation list.

So its fine.

(This ignores [custom event accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/how-to-declare-custom-events-to-avoid-blocking), but any implementation of those should try to follow the same pattern)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is absolutely fine to call `RemoveHandler`, regardless of calling `AddHandler` before.

But if you really like to please your colleague for the sake of it, then you could use the following check. I created a WinForms form with just a button called "Button1" on it. Here's the code behind:

```
Public Event Test As EventHandler

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'AddHandler Me.Test, Function(sender2 As Object, e2 As EventArgs)
    '                        Return Nothing
    '                    End Function

    If Me.TestEvent Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No event handler attached, RemoveHandler not necessary")
    Else
        MsgBox(String.Format("{0} event handler(s) attached, RemoveHandler for all subscriptions necessary", Me.TestEvent.GetInvocationList.Count))
    End If
End Sub
```

Microsoft creates an `EventHandler` object for every `Event` that is subscribed to, and names it like the event followed by "Event" (my event is called "Test" so the `EventHandler` is called "TestEvent").

So, if the `EventHandler` is `Nothing`, the event hasn't been subscribed to yet, and if it is not `Nothing`, you can even check how often it is subscribed to.